# Script to update IP addresses in config file

Tags: shell-script, sed

I'm writing a script that would prompt the user for the original IP and then the new IP. I can get sed to work from the CLI but wanted to make a script so users could update their own public IP's on a web server for access.

I'm getting the following errors but don't know why it's looking for EOF:

```
./UpdateIP.sh: line 24: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
 ./UpdateIP.sh: line 25: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script will change the IP address from x.x.x.x TO y.y.y.y

configs=/root/test.conf

echo "Please enter the IP Address to change:"

# Ask user to input for IP address
read origip

echo "Please enter the NEW IP Address to be changed to:"
read newip


echo "The original IP in the lines below will be changed FROM:
sed 's/$(origip)/$(newip)/' $(configs) | grep $(origip)
echo "TO:"
sed 's/$(origip)/$(newip)/' $(configs) | grep $(newip)

read -p "Press [Enter] key to start updating IP's..."
```

Comment: Missing `"` here: `echo "The original IP in the lines below will be changed FROM:`

Comment: Consider using https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Note also that `$(configs)` would try to run a command called `configs`.  What you want here (and in other similar situations) is probably `"$configs"` (including the double quotes).

Comment: There is a lot of error checking that needs to be put into such a script before I'd put it in production.  Like bad form, ranging, and of course what do you do about duplicates.

Comment: You have now changed the question, invalidating at least one correct answer to the original question. Don't do that. If you have further questions _after having accepted an answer to your original question_ (which was explicitly about a syntax error in your code), then you should instead open a _new question_.  I have rolled back the text of the question to the original.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below script for updating new ip adress

Tested  and it worked fine

```
script

#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the old ip adress which need to change"
read oldip
echo "enter the new ip adress"
read newip

sed -i "s/$oldip/$newip/g" configfilename
```

Comment: Some user validation needs to be done: the sed `s` command will "break" if the input contains a slash

Comment: Also, the dots in the IP address probably need escaping in the pattern, and the input needs to be validated as an IP address, or a user could just enter `.*` and destroy the configuration.

Comment: Correcting the code

Comment: Any recommendations to a simple method to validate the IP address?